# not sure how to add strength modifier in DnD Kata

Tags: c#, tdd

I started coding on the Everquest TDD Kata ([Github Link](https://github.com/PuttingTheDnDInTDD/EverCraft-Kata)) and I'm on the part about

> Feature: Character Ability Modifiers Modify Attributes
>
> As a character I want to apply my ability modifiers improve my capabilities in combat so that I can vanquish my enemy with extreme prejudice
>
> add Strength modifier to:
>
> - attack roll and damage dealt
> - double Strength modifier on critical hits

but I can't figure out if my math is right on my test. Using NUnit's TestCaseSource I have the following test

```
[TestFixture]
public class CharacterAbilityTests
{
    [TestCaseSource("StrengthAbilityTestCases", Category = "Character Strength Tests")]
    public int StrengthAbiltyAddsModifierToAttackRollAndDamage(Character hero, int hitroll)
    {
        var enemy = new Character();
        Assert.That(hero.Attack(enemy, hitroll), Is.True);

        return enemy.HitPoints;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> StrengthAbilityTestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(12).RollsHitOf(9).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(3);
            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(14).RollsHitOf(8).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(2);
            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(16).RollsHitOf(7).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(1);
            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(19).RollsHitOf(6).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(0);
            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(20).RollsHitOf(5).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(-1);

            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(12).RollsHitOf(20).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(2);
            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(14).RollsHitOf(20).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(0);
            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(16).RollsHitOf(20).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(-2);
            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(19).RollsHitOf(20).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(-4);
            yield return My.Hero.WithStrength(20).RollsHitOf(20).LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(-6);
        }
    }
    private class My
    {
        private Character hero;
        private int hitRoll;

        public static My Hero { get { return new My(); } }
        private My() { hero = new Character(); }

        public My WithStrength(int strength){hero.Strength = strength;return this;}
        public My RollsHitOf(int hitRoll) { this.hitRoll = hitRoll; return this; }

        public TestCaseData LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(int expectedHitPoints)
        {
            var testCaseData = new TestCaseData(hero, hitRoll)
            {
                HasExpectedResult = true,
                ExpectedResult = expectedHitPoints,
                TestName = $"Hero with Stength of {hero.Strength} rolling a {hitRoll} Should leave enemy with {expectedHitPoints} Hit points"
            };

            return testCaseData;
        }
    }
}
```

And all of my tests that deal with critical hits are failing (the last 5 tests) The thing is I'm not sure that my math is right. This is my attack method: (Mind you that all of my previous tests are currently passing)

```
public class Character
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Alignment Alignment { get; set; }
    public int ArmorClass { get; private set; }
    public int HitPoints { get; private set; }
    public bool IsDead { get { return HitPoints <= 0; } }

    public Ability Strength { get; set; }
    public Ability Dexterity { get; set; }
    public Ability Constitution { get; set; }
    public Ability Wisdom { get; set; }
    public Ability Intelligence { get; set; }
    public Ability Charisma { get; set; }

    public Character()
    {
        ArmorClass = 10;
        HitPoints = 5;
        Strength = 10;
        Dexterity = 10;
        Constitution = 10;
        Wisdom = 10;
        Intelligence = 10;
        Charisma = 10;
    }

    public bool Attack(Character enemy, int hitRoll)
    {
        var damage = 0;
        var modifier = IsCritHit(hitRoll) ? Strength.Modifier * 2 : Strength.Modifier;
        var isEnemyHit = IsCritHit(hitRoll) || (enemy.ArmorClass <= (hitRoll + modifier));

        if (!isEnemyHit) return false;

        damage = 1 + modifier;
        if (IsCritHit(hitRoll)) damage *= 2;
        enemy.TakeDamage(damage);

        return true;
    }

    private static bool IsCritHit(int hitRoll)
    {
        return hitRoll == 20;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        HitPoints-= damage;
    }
}

public class Ability
{
    public int Score { get; private set; }
    public int Modifier { get; private set; }

    private Ability(int score)
    {
        Score = score;
        Modifier = (int)(Math.Floor((Score - 10) / 2.0));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Score} [{Modifier}]";
    }
    public static implicit operator int(Ability ability)
    {
        return ability.Score;
    }

    public static implicit operator Ability(int score)
    {
        return new Ability(score);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I forgot that the magic numbers for AC and HP are 10 and 5 respectively. They are from the specs of the Kata.

**EDIT 2.0**

here is the output of the first of my 5 failing tests

```
Test Name:  Hero with Stength of 12 [1] rolling a 20 Should leave enemy with 2 Hit points
Test FullName:  EmptyProject.Tests.CharacterAbilityTests.Hero with Stength of 12 [1] rolling a 20 Should leave enemy with 2 Hit points
Test Source:    D:\Users\Robert\Source\Repos\EverCraft-Kata\dotNet\src\EmptyProject.Tests\CharacterAbilityTests.cs : line 14
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.012

Result StackTrace:  
at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
at NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestActionCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
Result Message: 
Expected: 2
  But was:  -1
```

**Edit hopefully final**

I suppose I mean to ask is it supposed to be (`baseDamage`+`strengthModifier`) * 2, or is it (`baseDamage` *2) + `strengthModifier`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.LeavesEnemyWithHitPoints(2)` is wrong. It should be -1.

This section of code:

```
var damage = 0;
var modifier = IsCritHit(hitRoll) ? Strength.Modifier * 2 : Strength.Modifier;
var isEnemyHit = IsCritHit(hitRoll) || (enemy.ArmorClass <= (hitRoll + modifier));

if (!isEnemyHit) return false;

damage = 1 + modifier;
if (IsCritHit(hitRoll)) damage *= 2;
    enemy.TakeDamage(damage);
```

With a `Strength.Modifier` of 1, your `modifier` calculation yields 2 on a critical hit. This means that `damage = 1 + modifier` is 3. Because you've rolled a critical hit, damage doubles making your total `damage` = 6. If the enemy's total HP is 5 and you hit him for 6, he should have -1 HP.

I don't know if that's the correct DnD calculation (can't remember)

Comment: I think the only thing it lacks from full DnD calculation is Weapon damage roll + abilities

Comment: I realize it's been a few years, but when I wrote this, the intention was  (baseDamage+strengthModifier) * 2 and at least 1 point of damage is always done. Hope you had fun with the exercise!

Answer (score 1):

It's `(baseDamage+strengthModifier) * 2`

However, when non-critical, if Strength is less than 10, and the modifier is negative, then the damage you actually do is negative or zero, which doesn't sound reasonable. I mean if you have Strength 6 and hit someone, you actually give that player 1 hit point? And if it's critical you give 2 hit points? :P The problem description is not clear in this part